# Timestamp not updated for records changed using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM 

INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1, 3, now());
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(2, 5, now());
```

I expected to see the timestamp of the last change to a record in the column 'modified'.

When I change a record using 
`UPDATE abc set number = 6 WHERE id = 1;`
all works fine.

But when using phpMyAdmin GUI to change a record the timestamp is not updated. A bug?
Is there a way to get the correct timestamp of the last change?
(`phpMyAdmin 4.1.0 and MySQL 5.1.63`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely phpmyadmin updates all cells even when you edited just one cell. As values for the other cells, he uses the old values. And when the `modified` is set up manually (phpmyadmin set it up to old value), `ON UPDATE` will not process.

To force automatic update on this cell and override any manual (or phpmyadmin-automatical) input, add a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON `abc`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.modified = NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one caught me too... the update DOES happen in the database, but phpMyAdmin doesn't update the display of columns it thinks weren't changed.